# sql table with primary key from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

This question are going to probably be very basic but I am new to SQL. I am trying to create a new table based of a previous table that will use the primary key from the orinal table and display the value of that id.

Table_1:

```
Field   Type            Null   Key       Default       Extra
-----   ----            ----   ---       -------       -----
ID      int(11)         NO     PRI                     auto_increment
fruit   varchar(255)    NO
```

The results are:

```
ID  fruit
--  -----
1   Apple
2   Orange
3   Pear
4   Grape
5   BlueBerry
6   StrwBerry
7   Kiwi
```

For table two I would like to be able to have a primary_id, table_1_id, table_1_name, color, location.

Something like this:

```
ID  table_1_id  table_1_fruit_name   color   location
--  ----------  ------------------   -----   --------
1   1           Apple                Red     Farm
2   1           Apple                Green   Store
3   2           Orange               Orange  Store
4   4           Grape                Green   Farm
5   4           Grape                Green   Store
```

I am getting lost on how to create this. I have tried using constraints ( assuming that is what I should use ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
   CREATE TABLE mynewtable
    (
      location varchar(255),
      color varchar(255),
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      FOREIGN KEY (table_1_id) REFERENCES table_1(id),
      FOREIGN KEY (table_1_name) REFERENCES table_1(name),
    )
```

Comment: ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: My answer must be used without last comma.

Comment: What Database Management System do you use?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
 CREATE TABLE secondtable
(
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
  location varchar(50),
  color varchar(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (table1_name) REFERENCES table1(name),
)
```